# How do I create a TabControl with no tab headers?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tabs, tabcontrol

How do I make a tab manager that doesn't show the tab headers?

This is a winforms application, and the purpose of using a tab manager is so the display content can only be changed through code. It's good for menus where various menu options change the screen contents.

Comment: Is it winforms or web application?

Comment: @JPReddy how did you know you were supposed to add the **infragistics** tag?

Comment: Not enough information. What type of application is this (WinForms, WPF, Web, ...)? Are you using a 3rd party tab control (as suggested by @JPReddy's retagging), or the built-in tab control?

Comment: why do this? It makes no sense.

Comment: You've been asked to indicate the GUI lib on previous questions. Voting to close this.

Comment: @Henk Holterman "indicate the gui lib" - what's this??

Comment: @unicorn isn't this what panels are for?

Comment: @David: Some people think tab controls are a little easier than panels to interact with at design-time. I've seen a lot of (relatively poor) wizard control implementations that use this trick. Otherwise, I agree that a panel or usercontrol is the way to go here.

Comment: Hiding tabs on tab control is the common way of making wizards.  Even infragistics has 'mode' for a tabcontrol that hides tabs and calls it wizard mode :)

Comment: @daniel fair enough but it seems a little over the top to me.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Hiding the tabs on a standard `TabControl` is pretty simple, once you know the trick. The tab control is sent a [`TCM_ADJUSTRECT` message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb760573.aspx) when it needs to adjust the tab size, so we just need to trap that message. (I'm sure this has been answered before, but posting the code is easier than searching for it.)

Add the following code to a new class in your project, recompile, and use the `CustomTabControl` class instead of the built-in control:

```
class CustomTabControl : TabControl
{
    private const int TCM_ADJUSTRECT = 0x1328;

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        // Hide the tab headers at run-time
        if (m.Msg == TCM_ADJUSTRECT && !DesignMode)
        {
            m.Result = (IntPtr)1;
            return;
        }

        // call the base class implementation
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}
```

(Code sample originally taken from [Dot Net Thoughts](http://www.dotnetthoughts.net/tag/tcm_adjustrect/).)

Note that this will not work properly for tab headers positioned on the sides or the bottom. But not only does that just look weird, you won't be able to see the tabs at run-time anyway. Just put them on the top where they belong.

Comment: @Nate Shoffner @Cody Gray
I tried that, but when i dragged the new tab manager to the designer i get error: Falied to create component

Comment: @unicorn: What's the *rest* of the error say? Did you rebuild the project first? I know this works, so there has to be something else wrong.

Comment: the line 'base.WndProc(ref m);' was commet, fixed it and works fine, thanks :)

Comment: I'm sure this has been answered before as well.  Attribution is a big deal around here.

Comment: @Hans: I don't remember where I originally learned this, so I didn't think provide any particular attribution. A Google search turns up [this link](http://www.dotnetthoughts.net/tag/tcm_adjustrect/), which appears the most likely candidate. I'll update the answer with attribution.

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/c290832f-3b84-4200-aa4a-7a5dc4b8b5bb/

Comment: @CodyGray – perhaps you can add a note that the solution is not functionally complete, if one wants to use tab control as multi-page switcher. The loophole is that  users are still able to change tabs using `Ctrl+(Shift+)Tab` or `Ctrl+PgUp/PgDn` even if they are hidden. Implementors should refer to post from June 22, 2012 at [original source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912354/how-do-i-create-a-tabcontrol-with-no-tab-headers#comment9728806_4912564) for effective way to avoid this.

Answer (score 1):

Right, if it's web application, you can build your own DIV with the same placement and hide/show as per your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Along with everybody else, I find your question a bit confusing.  I've used this method found [here](http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread215150.html) before.  Using this way you have a single property you can change as to whether you want to show the tab headers or not.

Answer (score 0):

After the edit and comments made the question more clear, I think the normal way to handle this is to use multiple panels rather than tabs.

Comment: how exacly that help? say i need 3 screens.. how do i do it?

Comment: but how can i switch between them when i'n in designer? they on top eachother, no?

Comment: @unicorn: Right-click on a panel control, and select "Send To Back" or "Bring To Front".

Comment: @Cody that will work, but the more screens i've got the messier this will be, i still think that tab control with invisible tab header is better..

Comment: @unicorn: Another option is to design each of the "panels" as a separate `UserControl`, and then just add them to your form at run-time using code. That's generally the way I do this. This approach has the benefit of increasing encapsulation. All of your code is separated by the specific panel that it applies to, rather than all being dumped into one giant form class.

Comment: +1 @Cody It's easy to get tied to the designer but for more complex UI like this then runtime coding usually makes it all simple again

Answer (score 0):

I guess, that using panels is the simplest solution. In addition, I suggest using my (free, opensource) `VisualStateManager` to simplify switching and eliminate lots of `.Enabled = true` horrors.

Package is available [on Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/VisualStateManager).

Just write this code:

```
// Contains and propagates information about current page
private SwitchCondition<int> settingPageCondition;
// Controls state of specific controls basing on given SwitchCondition
private VisualStateSwitchController<int> settingPageController;

// (...)

private void InitializeActions()
{
    // Initialize with possible options
    settingPageCondition = new SwitchCondition<int>(0, 1);

    settingPageController = new VisualStateSwitchController<int>(
        null,                  // Enabled is not controlled
        null,                  // Checked is not controlled
        settingPageCondition,  // Visible is controller by settingPageCondition
        new SwitchControlSet<int>(0, pGeneral),   // State 0 controls pGeneral
        new SwitchControlSet<int>(1, pParsing));  // State 1 controls pParsing
}

// (...)

public void MainForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    InitializeActions();
}

// (...)

// Wat to set specific page
settingPageCondition.Current = 0;
```