# Controling Tab page changes Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I am building a .Net 3.5 WinForms based questionnaire comprising 9 steps (each on a tab page using a TabControl control). I would like users to move to the next tab ONLY when they click a "Next Step" button I've provided and not jump to later steps by clicking on the tab buttons above. 
Basically, I dont want them to see contents of later steps/tab pages without completing the current step/tab page they are on, and then clicking my "Next Step" button.
Any ideas would be appreciated. Cheers.

Comment: The following two links should help you achieve what you want - http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/csharp/threads/215150 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912354/how-do-i-create-a-tabcontrol-with-no-tab-headers. You might be better off writing a user control with a series of panels, then a single property or method for changing the current panel. This would make your UI code a lot cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

you can create your tabe pages and remove all pages except first page by

Like

```
 tabControl1.TabPages.Remove(tabPage2);
.
.
.
 tabControl1.TabPages.Remove(tabPageN);
```

and after each  click of next button
add  proper page (may be next page ) to tabecontrol

```
    tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tabPage2);
```

and

```
    tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tabPage3);
```