# WinForm TabControl: How to hide/show tab headers dynamically?

Tags: winforms, tabcontrol

I want to make my tabControl a little smarter to save some screen real estate: Don't show tab header if there is only one tab and show tab headers if there are two or more tabs.

I know that you can hide the tab header completely as suggested at [How do I create a TabControl with no tab headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912354/how-do-i-create-a-tabcontrol-with-no-tab-headers). The problem with this approach is that, once hidden, I cannot show the tab header again. Or did I miss something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Crediting the guy that actually [came up with the idea](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/c290832f-3b84-4200-aa4a-7a5dc4b8b5bb/):

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class WizardPages : TabControl {
    private bool tabsVisible;

    [DefaultValue(false)]
    public bool TabsVisible {
        get { return tabsVisible; }
        set {
            if (tabsVisible == value) return;
            tabsVisible = value;
            RecreateHandle();
        }
    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
        // Hide tabs by trapping the TCM_ADJUSTRECT message
        if (m.Msg == 0x1328) {
            if (!tabsVisible && !DesignMode) {
                m.Result = (IntPtr)1;
                return;
            }
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Grave digging a bit but I know of another solution. I have no idea where it came from but here it is:

In form load: (VB.NET)

```
Tabcontrol1.Region = New Region (New RectangleF(TabPage1.Left, TabPage1.Top, TabPage1.Width, TabPage1.Height))
```

Where `TabControl1` is the name of your tab control and `TabPage1` is the name of the first tab page in that control.

If you wanted to make it usable as a routine then you could do something like this:

```
Public Sub hideTabs(ByVal TC as TabControl)
    TC.Region = New Region(New RectangleF(TC.TabPages(0).Left,TC.TabPages(0).Top, TC.TabPages(0).Width, TC.TabPages(0).Height))
End Sub
```

It is that easy. What is nice about this is that the headers are not shown at runtime but they are visible at design time.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Hans's answer:

I wanted to have the TabControl able to hide tabs in design time too, but then there was a problem, that once you hide the tabs, there is no way to select the TabControl to turn them on again, so i created a custom TabPage, that is able to control this property

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Public Class NoHeaderTabPage
Inherits TabPage

Public Property ShowTabs() As Boolean
    Get
        Return CType(Me.Parent, NoHeaderTabControl).ShowTabs
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
        CType(Me.Parent, NoHeaderTabControl).ShowTabs = value
    End Set
End Property

End Class
```