# How to change one panel to another panel during runtime?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am trying to make a multiple page application using winforms. I decied to use multiple Panels - each panel represents different page, so I can switch between them when I need to display different content. 
 My problem during run time is when i try to switch between panels its not working.

My Code:

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    panel2.Visible = false;
}

private void label4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    panel1.Visible = true;
}

private void label5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    panel2.Visible = true;
    panel1.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: What is not working, could you describe it a bit better?

Comment: I guess that you are just missing **panel2.Visible = false;** in **label4_Click** event handler.

Comment: IMO, a far better solution is to create a specialized `UserControl` for each panel. Control.Controls.Add(myUserPanel) or Control.Controls.Remove(myUserPanel) to switch out the panels. This avoids the issue of multiple panels within the same designer view.

Comment: I am trying to visible panel1 when label4 is clicked and panel2 must be visible wen label5 is clicked.panel1 is visible but panel2 is not visible wen i click label5

Comment: Does it even render to the client side?

Comment: A common problem with "stacking" Panels like this is that positioning them on the form right on top of each other often ends up with one Panel actually INSIDE another one (instead of being contained by the Form itself).  This may not be obvious just by looking at them on the form!  The suggestion of a UserControl instead of a Panel by Amoolya can prevent this kind of problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    panel2.Visible = false;
}

private void label4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    panel1.Visible = true;
    panel2.Visible = false;
}

private void label5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    panel2.Visible = true;
    panel1.Visible = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on **how you layout your panels**. I doubt that you haven't even added your panels to your form or you position your panel in a wrong place. I suppose you want to fill the `Panels` in your `Form`, we can use the `BringToFont()` method to show your panel instead. Try this:

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
  panel1.Dock = panel2.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
  panel1.Parent = panel2.Parent = this;//this refers to Form2
}

private void label4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  panel1.BringToFront();//show panel1
}

private void label5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
  panel2.BringToFront();//show panel2
}
```

**NOTE**: to see it in action you should be sure your `label4_Click`, `label5_Click` and `Form2_Load` are registered correctly. You should also set the `BackColor of`panel1`and`panel2` differently, like this:

```
//your Form2 constructor
public Form2(){
  label4.Click += label4_Click;
  label5.Click += label5_Click;
  Load += Form2_Load;
  panel1.BackColor = Color.Green;
  panel2.BackColor = Color.Red;
}
```

Because you fill your panels into all your form client rectangle, the `label4` should be added to `panel2` and `label5` should be added to `panel1`.

Answer (score 0):

in addition you  need to  re a locate the panel

```
panel1.Location = new Point(0, 0); //the preferd new postion
panel2.Location =new Point(1000,1000)//far away
panel2.Visible=false;
panel1.Visible=true;
```

Answer (score 0):

this is exactly because you are placing one panel on top of another panel and these panels are getting overlapped. 
hence you are not able to see at least one panel when you execute the program. there is no bug in program,but to avoid this issue please follow the below steps.

1.while loading the form please make sure that all panels are hidden initially.

2.while changing any panel visibility to true, make sure that remaining all panels visibility is set to false(hidden).

3.try to remove the panels overlapping with each other.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution to this, would be to use `TabControl` without headers, this is much easier to manage in IDE, as you see the tabs, and can switch between them during Design Time, and they are hidden at run time.

See this:
[How do I create a TabControl with no tab headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912354/how-do-i-create-a-tabcontrol-with-no-tab-headers)

Great for wizards etc. :-)

Just add buttons that change the current active tab.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tabControl1.SelectTab("tabPage2");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If panel2 is inside panel1, panel1 will become the parent of panel2 (instead of your form). If this is the case then setting panel2 as visible will have no effect if the parent (panel1) is hidden. You can try placing the panels side by side, and see if clicking the buttons work.

A workaround to this issue is to set the **Parent** property in code:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        panel1.Parent = this;
        panel2.Parent = this;           
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I go like this: as I name the panels, all their names start with "pnl". As there is a propriety with the name of the object, we can search for it like this

```
private void panelVibility(Control ctr)
{
    foreach (Control item in this.Controls)
    {
        if (item.Name.StartsWith("pnl"))
        {
            item.Location = new Point(12, 27);
            item.Visible = false;
        }
    }
    ctr.Visible = true;
}
```

them you send the panel you want to turn visible as a parameter when you call the method through a button_Click for example.

```
private void btnPnl1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    panelVibility(pnl1);
}
```